# How to make angular faster when data binding it not required

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Comparing [angular](http://angularjs.org/) with other libraries like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for redering a list I notice about a 10x performance hit.

The table does not have to change when the model changes. If required I can redraw the table on button press or some other event.

Here is a plunkr with the comparison:
http://plnkr.co/edit/uwaNDVuPN4KvxRovdBfw?p=preview

1.) Am I timing angular correctly?

2.) Is there any way to speed up angular when binding is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this **bind-once** directives: https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

It will bind you value only once to your view, and then delete the watcher. It will be much much faster.

Comment: I looked at bindonce previously and thought it did not make any difference to my use case. However, I've tried again and it does seem to speed things up: http://plnkr.co/edit/x4GoWrly3oAgdxSeaoFj?p=preview But it is still about 3x slower than handlebars.

Comment: Scrap previous comment. Bindonce does not make any difference to my use case, still 10x slower than Handlebars:
http://plnkr.co/edit/x4GoWrly3oAgdxSeaoFj?p=preview